# Intuition for expectation of random variable as an integral of probability

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable on some probability space.

Assume $X\in L^1$.
Then, a theorem says:

$$E[X] = \int_0^\infty P(X>t) \, dt$$

What would be an **intuitive explanation** for this theorem? 
I would like to get an intuitive feel for why the theorem should be true.

I mean, why should the "infinite Riemann sum" $\sum  P(x>t) \, \Delta t$ be equal to the expectation of $X$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum $\sum\limits_{x=1}^\infty \Pr(X\ge x)$ can be written as the sum of the following rows:
$$
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
\Pr(X\ge 1) & = & \Pr(X=1) & + & \Pr(X=2) & + & \Pr(X=3) & + & \Pr(X=4) & + & \cdots \\
\Pr(X\ge 2) & = & & & \Pr(X=2) & + & \Pr(X=3) & + & \Pr(X=4) & + & \cdots \\
\Pr(X\ge 3) & = & & & & & \Pr(X=3) & + & \Pr(X=4) & + & \cdots \\
\Pr(X\ge 4) & = & & & & & & & \Pr(X=4) & + & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & & & & & & & & \vdots
\end{array}
$$
The first vertical column to the right of $\text{“}{=}\text{''}$ adds up to $1\cdot\Pr(X=1)$, the second to $2\cdot\Pr(X=2)$, the third to $3\cdot\Pr(X=3)$, and so on, so they all add up to $\sum\limits_{x=1}^\infty x\Pr(X=x)$, which is $\operatorname{E}(X)$.

There's no need to assume $X\in L^1$.  This holds if $\Pr(X\ge0)=1$ regardless of whether $\operatorname{E}(X)<\infty.$

Comment: That description only works in the discrete setting, though one can more generally pass to a discrete approximation and work this way.

Comment: @Ian What do you mean? OP is asking for intuition. The statement is in fact the continuous analogue for the easily understandable discrete setting

Comment: @BCLC I wasn't saying it was a bad answer, just ensuring that the content of the answer is understood, in particular that $\sum_{x=1}^\infty xPr(X=x)=E(X)$ assumes that (the law of) $X$ is concentrated on $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Ian : That's true: If the question had asked for a proof of the statement in the form in which it appeared in the question, this would certainly fall short of answering that. $\qquad$

Comment: @Did : $\displaystyle \sum_{x=1}^\infty x\Pr(X=x)$ is hardly ever equal to $\operatorname{E}(X)$ when $\Pr(X\in\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}) \ne 1$. For example, if $X= 1 \pm \frac 1 2$ each with probability $1/2$, then $\operatorname{E}(X)=1$ but $\displaystyle \sum_{x=1}^\infty x\Pr(X=x) =0$. $\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$ Or rather I should say "hardly every equal to $\operatorname{E}(\lfloor X\rfloor)$".  In the example in my comment above, $\operatorname{E}(\lfloor X\rfloor) = 1/2$, but $\displaystyle \sum_{x=1}^\infty x\Pr(X=x) =0$. $\qquad$ @Did $\qquad$

Comment: You are right, this part of my comment is bogus. To reiterate the meaningful part: The answer should mention that when $X$ is nonnegative and integer valued then $\sum\limits_{x=1}^\infty xP(X=x)=E(X)$ but that when $X$ is not integer valued, the identity fails in general.